# Explicit template instantiation of class with static member in static library

Tags: c++, static-members, static-initialization

The question I am about to ask is related to a C++ library with persistency support that I am working on. However, I managed to strip down my issue in a simple example, therefore I won't go into details on my original scenario, unless someone is interested in it.

In [this resumed example](https://github.com/orlandini/StaticInitializationTest), I want to be sure that the explicit instantiation (src/TExampleClass.cpp):

```
template class TRestoreClass<TExampleClass<int>>;
```

will initialise the variable (include/TRestoreClass.h):

```
TRestoreClass<TExampleClass<int>> TRestoreClass<TExampleClass<int>>::pRestore;
```

Currently, when I run the code, everything goes well and my output is:

```
/pathToExecutable/StaticTest
TRestoreClass<TExampleClass<int> >::TRestoreClass() [T = TExampleClass<int>]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However, if I change the CMakeLists.txt to generate a STATIC library, my output is:

```
/pathToExecutable/StaticTest

Process finished with exit code 0
```

and it seems that the instantiation does not happen.

Since I don't want to depend on luck to know whether or not this instantiation will happen, I have decided to post this question here. I apologise in advance if the formatting of this question is not adequate, I just wanted to be sure that all the information would be available here.

---

EDIT:
While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680757/cpp-file-with-a-single-global-variable-is-ignored) is indeed similar, for me is still not clear:
- Why did it work if I am using a shared library? Is that guaranteed?
- Should I resort to write the explicit instantiation on the header files which, as far as I know, is not considered a good practice? Because that is the compiler-independent solution in the answers from that question, from what I have read.

---

I appreciate the attention, and here you can find the information detailing the problem:

- Directory and file structure:

```
├── include
|   ├── TRestoreClass.h
|   └── TExampleClass.h
├── src
|   ├── TExampleClass.h
└── main.cpp
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

- CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(StaticTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_library(libTest SHARED
        src/TExampleClass.cpp
        )
target_include_directories(libTest PUBLIC include)


add_executable(StaticTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(StaticTest libTest)
```

- include/TRestoreClass.h:

```
#ifndef STATICTEST_TRESTORECLASS_H
#define STATICTEST_TRESTORECLASS_H

#include <iostream>
template<class T>
class TRestoreClass {
public:
    TRestoreClass(){
    std::cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<std::endl;
    /**IMPORTANT STUFF SHOULD HAPPEN HERE**/
}
private:
    static TRestoreClass<T> pRestore;

};

template<class T>
TRestoreClass<T> TRestoreClass<T>::pRestore;


#endif //STATICTEST_TRESTORECLASS_H
```

- include/TExampleClass.h:

```
#ifndef STATICTEST_TEXAMPLECLASS_H
#define STATICTEST_TEXAMPLECLASS_H

template< class T>
class TExampleClass {
public:
    T obj;
};


#endif //STATICTEST_TEXAMPLECLASS_H
```

- src/TExampleClass.cpp:

```
#include "TExampleClass.h"


#include "TRestoreClass.h"
template class TRestoreClass<TExampleClass<int>>;
```

- main.cpp:

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680757/cpp-file-with-a-single-global-variable-is-ignored

Comment: Per Sneftel: possible duplicate of [cpp file with a single global variable is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680757/cpp-file-with-a-single-global-variable-is-ignored) (since an explicitly instantiated variable is equivalent to a non-templated variable)

Comment: @Sneftel, thank you very much for this reference. However, IMHO, I don’t think it answers the question. 1) why precisely does it work with the shared library? 2) should I really resort to what is typically considered a bad practice, eg., explicit template instantiation in the header files?

Comment: It really does answer the question. The linker has different tactics for object files and static libraries, but that's just that linker. It isn't guaranteed to *ever* work.

Comment: @Sneftel, I have edited the question (just before all the source code) in order to make myself clear. Maybe it’s due my lack of knowledge, but I am still unsure on how to proceed and whether I can rely on the initialization of the static member if I am generating a shared library. Despite of these doubts, thank you very much for your input.

Comment: No, you cannot rely on the initialization unless you follow the steps in the linked question. The fact that it works when you *aren't* using a static library is a non-guaranteed implementation detail.

Comment: Oh, and none of that is specific to the use of templates, which I think might be confusing your view of the problem. Since you're explicitly instantiating, the template-ness of it all doesn't have a relevant impact on the linking process.

Comment: @Sneftel, thanks again!
It's good to know that I cannot rely simply on using a shared library.

Regarding the steps on the other question: if I understood the problem correctly, I should make sure that 
````
static TRestoreClass<TExampleClass<int>> pRestore;
````
is referenced somewhere else in another translation unit to guarantee the proper initialisation: is this correct?